# Memory allocation -How can I relate program level and physical level?

Tags: memory-management, computer-science, cpu-architecture

When learning languages like java or C, we learn about static and dynamic memory allocations. The definitions given for these are somewhat like below

```
 Static memory allocation - memory is allocated in stack during compile time.
 Dynamic memory allocation - memory is allocated in heap during run time.
```

When considering the computer architecture, it is said that if the size of the variables exceed more than the L1 cache, it needs to be loaded from L2 cache or main memory and lot of replacements will occur. According to my understanding, L1 caches are usually in just kilobytes so in case of programs with large variables such as an array of size 10 million, how can that much memory be allocated at the compile time?

Please provide an insight into how I can map between the memory allocated at physical level and at the program level?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to separate two concepts here... That of memory allocation and that of memory access.

Memory Allocation is a software thing, it has very little to do with anything in the architecture. When a program is allocated memory via either static or dynamic allocation, the operating system sets aside pages of memory for use by the program. This can be an arbitrary amount (within the limits of the architecture of course), and the operating system can even swap pages in and out of physical memory in case the program requires more memory than is available.

Memory Access, however, is where the physical aspect of the architecture and caches come into play. Suppose, as per your scenario, a program has an array of size 10 million. The physical computer architecture doesn't know that there is an array of size 10 million. All it knows is that there are sizeof(array of 10 million) bytes accessible to the current running thread. The L1 and L2 cache do not operate on the programming language level and so they are not aware of the array or the data type or any such related thing. What it is aware of though is what parts of memory a program is accessing. The architecture will cache these memory accesses and push data in and out of cache according to how the memory is accessed, not according to how it is allocated. Therefore, to the architecture there is no difference between an array of 10 million elements and an assemblage of objects and primitives of any type taking up the same space. It simply sees everything as bytes and accesses.